# Parasite that controls galaxy empress

Tags: story-identification

Read this (maybe) in the early 1980s. I have faint memories only.

Some guy, possibly ex-military, in a monastery, gets a visit.  His friend wants him to help in a rebellion against an evil galactic Empress (or maybe she's the consort to the Emperor).

Lots of adventures later and they're at the final confrontation.  Her robe gets ripped off and there's like a big black parasite thing all around her torso.  It's been in symbiosis throughout her evil reign. I think the emperor has one as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely Brunner's "[The Altar on Asconel](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3275)" as I [previously asked about](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/237129/101407).  The scene with the robe being ripped off:

> He whirled, and was quick enough to grasp her by the robe as she made to flee. The robe tore, fell away, exposed her maggot-pale body to the pitiless glare of the noontide sun. There was utter silence. During it, Spartak felt nausea rise to choke his throat. Lydis was not a human mutant, accidentally gifted with the power to read minds. She was a tool of Belizuek. And instead of breasts on the front of her torso, she had a black pulsating growth that squirmed and leaked a stinking ichor as it followed its alien parent into the doorway of death.